# Cannot get argparse to correctly parse my arguments in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

Total python newb. Sorry.

Anyway, I'm using PyCharm and I'm trying to pass arguments to my python script. In pycharm, in the 'Edit Run Configuration' dialog box, in the Parameters text box, I have the following text:

```
-s "C:\temp\" -a "C:\Temp\archive\"
```

In my script I have a function called ParseAndValidateArguments, shown below:

```
def ParseAndValidateArguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-q", default=False, action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("-s",  type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-a",  type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

What's happening is that the -s argument is ending up with "C:\temp" -a"C:\Temp\archive" and the -a argument is getting nothing, resulting in the following error:

```
usage: SmArchive.py [-h] [-q] -s S -a A
SmArchive.py: error: the following arguments are required: -a
Process finished with exit code 2
```

I've tried it with spaces between the -s and the directories, I've tried it without. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

(By the way, I'm an old C# guy, and I'm telling you, they need to port argparse to the .NET framework because the console apps in .NET just get an array of strings. Nothing else. Here you go, just a chuck of strings, enjoy. You've got no idea if its an argument or a value, or what the heck it is. WTF????)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Try using ```\\``` in place of the ```\```.

Comment: The problem is the escaped double-quote.  In this SPECIFIC example, you don't need the quotes.  Another potential solution is to remove the trailing backslash.